# Firebase Auth UI Android, task returned by getIdToken() never completes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

After a successful login, I am unable to get the id token using the getIdToken() method.
This method returns a task and the task never completes. Using basic email id/password authentication using Firebase Auth UI in an android app.

```
new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build()
```

Here is the library version:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.1.0'
```

Here is how I am fetching the token:

```
public String getIdToken(){

        String token = null;
        Task<GetTokenResult> task = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getIdToken(true);
        while(!task.isComplete()){
        }
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            token = task.getResult().getToken();
        }else{
            token = "token_gen_failed";
        }
        return token;
}
```

The while loop never ends as the task never completes. How to wait for this task?
This code used to work when for firebase-UI-auth:3.2.2. Now I am trying to upgrade this library to 
6.1.0.

Any help here please, tried so many things.

All I see in the log is this:

```
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( xxxxxxxxxx ).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
task.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
   if(task.isSuccessful() & task.getResult() != null){
       token = task.getResult().getToken();
   }else{
     token = "token_gen_failed";
   }
   //do here whatever you want to do with token;
}
```

If you want to use this as a separate function then let me know. You have to do some extra task for it.